# How come Live Edit refresh much faster than Compose Preview?

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

*Compose Preview* takes on my Intel i7-4790 anywhere between 10 and 20 seconds to refresh a simple color or text modification. *Live Edit* on the other hand does it in sub-second time, even when my physical device is connected through wireless debugging.

What's the underlying mechanism that explains this huge discrepancy in refresh latency?

FYI I'm currently using `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4`.

I have checked these two resources below, but they don't seem to answer my question:

- [Live Edit](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/07/deep-dive-into-live-edit-for-jetpack-compose-ui.html)
- [Compose Preview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews)

I understand the benefits of using *Compose Preview* vs. *Live Edit*, so my question is not about that.

Comment: i think it's just live edit is not stable yet

Comment: @MohammadBaqer You mean Compose Preview right? Live Edit is blazingly fast.

Comment: yes i mean compose preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: The fix is to update Android Studio to (at least) version `Hedgehog | 2023.1.1`.

I installed the current latest version of Android Studio onto my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.3. To my pleasant surprise I noticed that *Compose Preview* was now **as fast** as *Live Edit*, i.e. sub-second time. My laptop has an even slower CPU than the i7-4790 installed in my desktop PC, so this huge speed upgrade was a bit remarkable and I was reluctant to think that a similar IDE upgrade to my desktop would do any difference. But it turns out it does. My desktop is now running `Hedgehog` and *Compose Preview* refreshes in sub-second time. Great!

Exactly what has been done is unclear, nothing about any speed-up for *Compose Preview* is mentioned in the release notes for `Hedgehog`. Could perhaps be the IDE itself, the SDKs, Gradle, or a combination of all these. They do mention the new improvement *[Windows-only] Minimize the impact of antivirus software on build speed*, but IIR I had already excluded the affected directories to Windows Defender's exclusion list. Plus I remember experiencing a slow *Compose Preview* on my Linux laptop (without antivirus software) before the IDE upgrade. But if you are running Windows and don't see any speed improvements to *Compose Preview* from `Hedgehog`, make sure to **allow the `Build Analyzer` in Android Studio to exclude the directories used by Gradle** (you should get a notification popup about this) as this *may* be the culprit.

Anyway, I'm both impressed and very content with the ~20x speed-up to *Compose Preview*. Thanks, Android Studio team!